# ProcessPoolExecutor and Lock in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, locking, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` with Locks, but I'm getting a run time error.
(I'm working on Windows if that's relevant)

Here's my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

import time


def f(i, lock):
    with lock:
        print(i, 'hello')
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i, 'world')


def main():
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    futures = [pool.submit(f, num, lock) for num in range(3)]
    for future in futures:
        future.result()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 242, in _feed
    obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "F:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "F:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\multiprocessing\synchronize.py", line 102, in __getstate__
    context.assert_spawning(self)
  File "F:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 347, in assert_spawning
    ' through inheritance' % type(obj).__name__
RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

What's weird is that if I write the same code with `multiprocessing.Process` it all works fine:

```
import multiprocessing

import time


def f(i, lock):
    with lock:
        print(i, 'hello')
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i, 'world')


def main():
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(i, lock)) for i in range(3)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works and I get:

```
1 hello
1 world
0 hello
0 world
2 hello
2 world
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use a `Manager` and use a `Manager.Lock()` instead:

```
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

import time

def f(i, lock):
    with lock:
        print(i, 'hello')
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i, 'world')

def main():
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    futures = [pool.submit(f, num, lock) for num in range(3)]
    for future in futures:
        future.result()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
% python locks.py
0 hello
0 world
1 hello
1 world
2 hello
2 world
```

Comment: It would be good to explain _why_ using `Manager.Lock()` solves the issue.

Comment: This is because `Manager.Lock()` can be pickled and `multiprocessing.Lock()` can't be.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented the code it's working as expected.
My understanding is **Manager.Lock()** returns the handle to acquire(i.e. multiprocessing.managers.AcquirerProxy). when it is used along with key word **"with"**, It actually locks all the processors except the current one so that the piece of code within the "with" scope acts as in the single processing.