# How to pass the "lock" in my concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, locking, python-multiprocessing

I am running a parallel test with Python 3.7 and Appium 1.15.1 on real Android smartphones.

I use **concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor** to run each test on each smartphone.

I am passing list of the uid of smartphones to my map function. By this way, my method 'run_smartphone()'(which start the test) get the uid of smartphone and identify on which smartphone it must run the test.

My script work fine without any issue. But **I would like to add a "lock"** because 'run_smartphone()' make some I/O on a sqlite3 database. So correct me if I am wrong, but it would be a good practice to "lock" the I/O operation on this sqlite3 database?

Here is my original code which works:

```
def run_smartphone(p_udid):
    #do the stuff

list_smartphones_connected = [41492968379078, 53519716736397]
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    try:
        multiprocesses = executor.map(mymodules.run_smartphone, list_smartphones_connected)

    except ValueError:
        print(("Error multiprocesses"))
```

So I tried to add pass "lock" to my method 'run_smartphone()'. This is what I wrote:

```
m = multiprocessing.Manager()
lock = m.Lock()
list_arguments_smartphones = []

list_smartphones_connected = [41492968379078, 53519716736397]
for smartphone_connected in list_smartphones_connected:        
    list_arguments_smartphones.append([smartphone_connected, lock])

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    try:
        multiprocesses = executor.map(mymodules.run_smartphone, list_arguments_smartphones)

    except ValueError:
        print(("Error multiprocesses"))
```

But it doesn't work and I don't get any exception raised. Pycharm stop the script :

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have no idea what is stopping the script.

So I started to investigate by executing the script for 1 smartphone with this line:

```
 multiprocesses = executor.map(mymodules.run_smartphone, [41492968379078,lock])
```

it gives the same result => The script stop, no automation start and I don't see any exception raised (Process finished with exit code 0).

As I wanted to know where exactly was the issue, I run the script with 'trace'.

```
py -m trace --trace  myscript.py
```

But I don't understand anything, I don't see any error...  You can see the output of this 'trace' command on a text file I uploaded on GitHub:

https://github.com/gauthierbuttez/public/blob/master/trace-log.txt

Does anyone have any idea how can I pass the "lock" to my concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() ?
And is it a good idea to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ProcessPoolExecutor and Lock in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394373/processpoolexecutor-and-lock-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this help you...

```
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()

    def run_smartphone(p_udid, lock): 
        # further code

    list_smartphones_connected = [41492968379078, 53519716736397] 
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: 
        try: 
            multiprocesses = executor.map(run_smartphone, list_smartphones_connected, [lock]*len(list_smartphones_connected)) 
            for function_return_value in multiprocesses:
                print(function_return_value)

        except ValueError: 
            print(("Error multiprocesses"))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) for map():

> If a func call raises an exception, then that exception will be raised
>   when its value is retrieved from the iterator.

In other words, you probably have to actually use the return value of run_smartphone:

```
m = multiprocessing.Manager()
lock = m.Lock()
list_arguments_smartphones = []

list_smartphones_connected = [41492968379078, 53519716736397]
for smartphone_connected in list_smartphones_connected:        
    list_arguments_smartphones.append([smartphone_connected, lock])

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    try:
        multiprocesses = executor.map(mymodules.run_smartphone, list_arguments_smartphones)

        for function_return_value in multiprocesses:
            print(function_return_value)
            # or do something with the value, like insert into a db

    except ValueError:
        print(("Error multiprocesses"))
```

But if you are having trouble even passing a lock to your function, and you haven't bothered reading the docs then I would suggest you restructure your code so that run_smartphone only reads from the database (shouldn't require a lock) and you write to the db in the for loop (doesn't require a lock).  Otherwise, you're going to get yourself into a deadlock quagmire.

Comment: Thank you. I run your script and get some error output : "TypeError: run_smartphone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lock'" . I don't understand why it said it is missing an argument?

Comment: ALso... I did read the doc, but it doesn't speak about 'lock'. :-(