# passing a lock to worker with ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking

#### tl;dr:

passing a lock to a `ProcessPoolExecutor` workers will make them not run.

---

I have a `JSON` file I want to update asynchronously using `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

to avoid a race condition, I want to use a common lock to the workers.
after trying both methods from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25558333/7142315) answer, and trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35394592/7142315) (which is the same but updated), the `process pool` still doesn't function as intended.

---

#### the code:

```py
def addToImageVector(path: str, lock):
    # to see if the process is running
    print('hi guy')
    
    # a real example of how I use the lock
    data: dict = None
    with lock:
        with open('path\\amounts.json', 'r') as f:
            data: dict = json.load(fp= f)
.
.
.

# inside another function, which is practically main

    for action in ACTIONS:
        lock = m.Lock()
        
        NUMBER_OF_CPUS = cpu_count()
        # use up to +++ of the cpu`s available 
        USE_UP_TO = 0.5
        
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=np.uint16(NUMBER_OF_CPUS * USE_UP_TO)) as executor:
            for file in os.listdir(normpath(VID_PATH + action)):
                # this gets printed
                print(colored(normpath(VID_PATH + action + file), 'green'))

                # doesn't work
                executor.submit(addToImageVector, (normpath(VID_PATH + action + file), lock))
```

#### the output:

```
path\boost\b1.mp4
path\boost\b2.mp4
path\boost\b3.mp4
path\boost\b4.mp4
path\boost\b5.mp4
...
path\click\c4.mp4
path\click\c5.mp4
path\click\c6.mp4
path\click\c7.mp4
...
path\click\c9.mp4
path\upgrade\u1.mp4
path\upgrade\u7.mp4
path\upgrade\u8.mp4
path\upgrade\u9.mp4
```

no `hi guy`s in the output.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: i tried to make one and caught the problem. it was the way workers take more then one argument, that made it fail.

Comment: I thought what you were claiming was the issue seemed unlikely — which is why I wanted something I could run myself — but am glad to hear you found the real problem.